# Работа с usb устройствами

Tags: c#, dll, usb

Есть примерно 10 USB устройств подключенных через USB-хаб. Для работы с устройствами есть библиотека производителя.

Импортирую библиотеку и пару методов с неё:

```
private const string ClscrflDll = "Clscrfl.dll";
[DllImport(ClscrflDll)]
public static extern uint CLSCRF_Create(ref IntPtr handle);

[DllImport(ClscrflDll)]
public static extern uint CLSCRF_OpenUSB(IntPtr pReader, uint dwIndex, uint dwLogFile);
```

Вызываю эти методы:

```
IntPtr pReader = new IntPtr();
CLSCRF_Create(ref pReader);
CLSCRF_OpenUSB(pReader, 8, 0);
```

Где второй параметр "8", у OpenUSB, это номер устройства. Проблема в том что к устройствам от 0 до 7 я подключаюсь без проблем, начиная с 8го, программа просто закрывается, не выдавая никаких ошибок/исключений и т.д.

Есть коллега, который на Delphi написал точно такой же код с этой же библиотекой, у него всё работает.

Пробовал ставить разные соглашения о вызове, не помогло. В чём ещё может быть проблема, может я что-то упустил?

В документации к библиотеке:

> `LONG CLSCRF_Create( IN OUT LPVOID* ppReader );`
>
> Создает объект-интерфейс. Эта функция должна вызываться 1 раз в начале
>   работы приложения.
>
> - `ppReader` – адрес переменной, в которую будет помещена ссылка на созданный
>     объект-интерфейс и которая будет использоваться в вызовах
>     всех остальных функций.`
>
> `LONG CLSCRF_OpenUSB( IN LPVOID pReader,IN DWORD dwIndex = 0,IN DWORD dwLogFile= 0 );`
>
> Открывает USB-интерфейс. Эта функция должна вызываться 1 раз перед началом
>   обмена со считывателем.
>
> - `pReader` – ссылка на объект-интерфейс (см. функцию CLSCRF_Create);
> - `dwIndex` – номер USB-устройства в дереве устройств от 0;
> - `dwLogFile` – вывод в файл хронологии обмена:
>
>   - 1 - создавать файл;
>   - 0 - не создавать файл.

---

**Проблему решил. При запуске программы из exe файла, программа работает нормально, из под студии почему-то валится. Отлаживать сложно будет, но ничего, в моём случае особых проблем это не принесёт.**

Comment: Это вопрос не к нам, а в техподдержку производителя устройств. Откуда мы знаем, как нужно с ним работать и какие нужны сигнатуры для P/Invoke? У нас даже документации нет.

Comment: @VladD, добавил текст из документации. Пишу именно сюда, т.к. может действительно я в коде ошибся, что-то упустил или вообще не понимаю. И для меня странно то, что на делфи эта же библиотека исправно работает.

Comment: В этой части кода и документации никаких проблем я не вижу. Но в другой части документации может быть описано что-то, что вы упускаете. Вы ведь не собираетесь выкладывать сюда **всю** документацию?

Comment: @VladD, весь документ состоит из краткого описания каждой функции библиотеки. Те что использую я, я выложил, больше ничего нет. Я с этой библиотекой работаю давно, от и до уже много раз читал. И в проекте ничего кроме этих строк кода нет, специально убрал всё лишнее. Брал пример программы самого производителя, чуть редактировал код и получал точно такую же проблему. Уже написал производителю, буду ждать ответ.

Comment: Может, вы открываете и не закрываете слишком много устройств? Или используете их из различных потоков?

Comment: @VladD, код который я выложил, прям вот его и использую. Т.е. если меняю 8 на 0...7, то подключение проходит, если ставлю больше 7, то ошибка.

Comment: Меня смущает, что `CLSCRF_Create` принимает указатель на `LPVOID`, в то время как `CLSCRF_OpenUSB` принимает `LPVOID` непосредственно. А вы и туда и туда передаете `IntPtr`. Я не уверен, но разве оно так работает? Или `ref` превращает его в указатель?

Comment: @playerone, create создаёт объект и ссылку на него возвращает в переменную, а openUSB пользуется этим объектом. Алгоритм рабочий, т.к. на маленьком количестве устройств уже не раз отрабатывался. Но и проблему я решил. В шапке написал.

Comment: @Николай Погодите. Еще раз: судя по документации я уверен, что `Create` принимает __указатель на__ переменную куда будет помещен адрес. Об этом говорит тип `LPVOID*` и даже префикс `pp` перед именем параметра. А `Open` принимает уже не указатель, а саму переменную (типа `LPVOID`), адрес которой дала вам `Open`. В этом я уверен. Но я не знаю как обращаться с этим из C# потому. что раньше такого не делал, и поэкспериментировать сейчас нет возможности.

Comment: @Николай Мне кажется, что после вызова `Create`, у вас в `pReader` появляется не то значение, что требуется передать в `Open`, а адрес памяти где нужное значение лежит. Из-за этого `Open` начинает писать в чужую память и программа у вас валится. Тот факт, что всё работает без студии - это просто совпадение, вызванное вероятно тем, что без студии программа грузится в другую область памяти. То есть сегодня она без студии работает, а завтра перестанет. Или приведет к проблемам в других приложениях.

Comment: @playerone, хорошо, допустим. Как тогда мне стоит попробовать сделать?

Comment: @Николай мне не приходилось на практике с этим сталкиваться, поэтому сам точно не знаю. Попробуйте так:
`using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
IntPtr pReader = new IntPtr();
CLSCRF_Create(ref pReader);
pReader = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(pReader);
CLSCRF_OpenUSB(pReader, 8, 0);`
Если не сработает, то может кто-то еще подскажет.

Comment: @playerone, исключение: `Попытка чтения или записи в защищенную память. Это часто свидетельствует о том, что другая память повреждена`. Таким вариантом как я предложил, уже давно пользуюсь, проблем никогда не было. Правда на 1 USB устройстве.

Comment: @Николай боюсь мне больше добавить нечего. У меня сейчас нет возможности на чем-то похожем поэкспериментировать и разобраться.

Comment: @playerone, всё таки ошибка была в библиотеке. Связался с разработчиками(правда по другому вопросу), они подправили её, все проблемы решили и вылеты сами прекратились.

Comment: @Николай что ж, значит в коде всё было правильно. Рад, что проблема решена.